# UIView with different height between xib and code

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib

In the iPad version of my application I have a `UIView`, subview of a `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`, created by the `xib` that has as its frame `(0.0, 1024, 437)`. When you run the application in the output frame is become `(0.0, 1024, 800)` accordingly with almost twice the height it should have. What does it mean? How can I solve it?

The code:

```
   //self.scrollView is a TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView

   CGFloat width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;//is correct
   CGFloat progY = 0;

    self.view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, progY, width, 
                          self.view1.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.view1];

    progY+= self.view1.frame.size.height;
   //is correct, the height is equal to that of the xib

    self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, progY, width, self.view2.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"the frame of view2 is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view2.frame));
    //the frame of view2 is {{0, 215}, {1024, 800}}
    //the height would be 437 as in xib

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.view2];

    progY+= self.view2.frame.size.height;//is wrong

    //....
```

Comment: how/where are u initializing the `UIView`?

Comment: If you have already set in the xib , then what is the need to change the frame programatically .I would not prefer to change the frame if view is already implemented in xib.

Comment: the UIView is already implemented in the xib, and I want to maintain the same height, instead it changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base view in your XIB probably has the wrong autoresizing properties et.

Have a look at the base view's autoresizing settings in the Size Inspector - it should not be connected to the lower end of the screen, and also not change height dynamically, then you're fine.

Comment: I checked the Size Inspector and is equal to the other view, where the height is right. Is there any other way?

Comment: The height IS right - but what about the red lines in the autoresizing image? Do you see three vertical red lines? That should be only one if you don't want the size to adjust to the container view you throw the view into - from the top of the screen to the top border of the view.

Comment: Now I found it, it was wrong the Size Inspector. Thank you very much

Comment: You are a saint! This problem has been bugging me for so long